# Jira: Burndown for number of issues assigned to an epic?

Tags: jira, burn-charts

We have a Kanban project and I would like to have a rather simply report, but it seems like I cannot do this with Jira itself!?

What I want:

A burndown chart showing the number of open issues related to a specific Epic. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks for your help.

Jira Version: v8.13.9

Answer (score 1):

In Jira epics usually have a "Issues in epic" section with a list of all related items to the the epic. This isn't a burndown chart but it does give you a visual representation of the items within an epic and their status.